# Como sabe qual a linha da planilha, no qual o item do listview selecionado está?

Tags: vba, listview

Preenchi meu ListView e apliquei um filtro, para que o usuário possa escolher os valores a serem observados.

No entanto, preciso que o usuário possa adicionar informações ao item selecionado e que esses valores sejam salvos na planilha fonte do banco de dados na mesma linha e em uma coluna vazia especifica através do botão “ADD ACTION”.

Eu tentei de várias maneiras e não sei se meu código também está fazendo sentido...

Obrigado a todos!

'''

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim lineDp As Integer
Dim Dp As Worksheet
Dim Ultima_coluna As Long
Dim ColH As ColumnHeader
Dim Index As Long

Set Dp = Sheets("Details Pipeline")

'Number of Rows count
 lineDp = Dp.Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row

'Number of Colums count - Ctrl + Shift + End
Ultima_coluna = Dp.Cells(lineDp, Dp.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = 4 To Ultima_coluna

If Dp.Cells(3, i).Value <> "" Then

For j = 1 To ListView1.ListItems.Count

    If ListView1.ListItems.Item(j).Checked Then

        txt_id = ListView1.ListItems.Item(j)
        Dp.Cells(j, i) = TextBox6.Text

     End If

Next j

End If

Next i
```

'''
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Crie um [mcve] com uns dados de exemplo numa tabela.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode carregar a lista atraves de um For e a primeira coluna colocar a linha que está o registro, porém você deixa essa coluna com a largura zerada na tabela.

Ex:

```
Private Sub CarregarListaEmail()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ul As Integer

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Emails")
ul = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

With lstEmail
    .Clear

    .ColumnCount = 7 'NÚMERO DE COLUNAS QUE CONTEM SUA TABELA

    ' OBSERVA QUE O PRIMEIRO '0 PT' É DA COLUNA QUE REPRESENTA O NÚMERO DA LINHA
    .ColumnWidths = "0 pt;170 pt;138,95 pt;38 pt;110 pt;60 pt;0 pt"

    If ul > 1 Then
        For Each lin In ws.Range("A2:A" & ul)
            .AddItem lin.Row
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = lin.Value
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = lin.Offset(0, 1).Value
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 3) = lin.Offset(0, 2).Value
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 4) = lin.Offset(0, 3).Value
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 5) = lin.Offset(0, 4).Value
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 6) = lin.Offset(0, 5).Value
        Next lin
    End If

End With
```

End Sub

Api quando você quiser manipular o registro na planilha é só usar o número da linha que da primeira coluna.
Meu exemplo é com ListBox, porém a lógica será a mesma para ListView.
Usei esse exemplo, pois tenho fácil aqui.